# MVPA related to the number of input features

Tags: svm

I'm trying to run MultiVariate Pattern Analysis on fNIRS data. Generally, it has been used in fMRI where people search for patterns linked to activation with generally a high number of input features (hundreds of voxels). In fNIRS, however, we have very few input features (aprx. 24 per hemisphere). When running the analysis on the whole hemisphere i don't get any significant difference in the accuracy of the classifier but when i reduce the number of features to a specific region of 9 channels the classifier gives significant results. Can anyone explain to me why this is the case? When I vary one or more channel the results change a lot? Is it better to use a higher amount of channels and therefore those results are more robust?

In this particular case, MVPA uses an SVM linear classifier.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific problem to fNIRS technology. Increasing the number of features does not necessarily lead to increasing the performance of the classifier. A few fNIRS channels may be introducing similar patterns among the classes which leads to poorer performance.

I recommend checking this fNIRS work for further details:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169260719324344

Best, 
Sérgio Novi